# Can a differential equation be non-linear and homogeneous at the same time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have searched for the definition of homogeneous differential equation. I have found definitions of linear homogeneous differential equation. Can a differential equation be non-linear and homogeneous at the same time? (If yes then) what is the definition of homogeneous differential equation in general?
                                                                             y'' + sin(y) = 0 is it homogeneous?

Comment: No, the word is only used in the context of linear equations.

Comment: It could be said homogeneous  if it is expressed in the form:$p(y',y)=0$ where $p$ is a *homogeneous polynomial of two variables*. Homogeneity is a notion  related to polynomials of several variables.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Actually, differential equations of form $y' = f(\frac{y}{x})$ are also called homogeneous. To OP: I think you've missed this entry in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation

Comment: @Evgeny Thanx for reply. I re-read that wikipedia page, but didn't get my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Well In my book its given that any function "$f(x,y)$" satisfying "$f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda ^n f(x,y) $" where $n$ is any integer,  is a homogeneous function and differential equation which involve homogeneous function is called homogeneous differential equation.

Well for the question if a non-linear differential equation can be homogeneous or not. Yes, of course it can be. Consider the differential equation,

$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm d x} = \frac{y^2-xy+x^2sin(\frac{y}{x})}{x^2} $
.

This equation is neither linear in x or y but it is homogeneous. As,

$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2-xy+x^2\sin (\frac {y}{x})}{x^2}$

$f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\frac{\lambda ^2y^2-\lambda ^2xy+\lambda ^2x^2\sin (\frac {\lambda y}{\lambda x})}{\lambda ^2x^2}$

Now dividing numerator and denominator by $\lambda ^2$

$f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\frac{y^2-xy+x^2\sin (\frac {y}{x})}{x^2} = \lambda ^0 .f(x,y)$

Hence the function and so the differential equation is homogeneous. Here neither x or y is linear but the differential equation is homogeneous.

Answer (score 3):

## General Homogeneity

Ibragimov [*A Practical Course in Differential Equations and Mathematical Modeling*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6446&panel=book_details), §3.1.3 "Homogeneous Equations", p. 93:

> An ordinary differential equation of an arbitrary order $$F(x,y,y',…,y^{(n)})=0$$ is said to be homogeneous [in general] if it is invariant under a scaling transformation (dilation) of the independent and dependent variables […]: $$\bar{x}=a^kx,\qquad\bar{y}=a^ly,$$ where $a>0$ is a parameter not identical with 1, and $k$ and $l$ are any fixed real numbers. The invariance means that $$F(\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{y}',…,\bar{y}^{(n)})=0,$$ where $\bar{y}'=d\bar{y}/d\bar{x}$, etc.

### Double Homogeneity

[*Ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6446&panel=book_details) p. 95:

> [A differential equation] is *double homogeneous* if […] it does not alter under the transformations $$\bar{x}=ax,\qquad\bar{y}=y,$$ and  $$\bar{x}=x,\qquad\bar{y}=ay,$$ with independent positive parameters $a$ and $b$, respectively.

### Type 1: Uniform Homogeneity

[*Ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6446&panel=book_details) §3.1.4 "Different types of homogeneity", p. 96:

> The uniformly homogeneous equations are invariant under the *uniform scaling*: $$\bar{x}=ax,\qquad \bar{y}=ay$$

The general form of this type of homogeneous equations is (cf. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html)): $$\frac{dy}{dx}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).$$

### Type 2: Homogeneity by Function

[*Ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6446&panel=book_details) p. 97:

> This type of homogeneity designates invariance […] with respect to the dilation of $y$ only: $$\bar{x}=x,\qquad \bar{y}=ay$$

This is the more common understanding of homogeneity:

Licker's [*Dictionary of Mathematics*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=4925&panel=book_details) p. 108 defines a homogeneous differential equation as

> A differential equation where every scalar multiple of a solution is also a solution.

Zwillinger's [*Handbook of Differential Equations*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6642&panel=book_details) p. 6:

> An equation is said to be homogeneous if all terms depend linearly on the dependent variable or its derivatives. For example, the equation $y_{xx} + xy = 0$ is homogeneous while the equation $y_{xx} + y = 1$ is not.

Olver's [*Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=6632&panel=book_details) p. 9:

> A differential equation is called *homogeneous linear* if both sides are sums of terms, each of which involves the dependent variable $u$ *or* one of its derivatives to the first power; on the other hand, there is no restriction on how the terms involve the independent variables. Thus, $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{u}{1+x^2}=0$$ is a homogeneous linear second-order ordinary differential equation.